# Insert one column from file, and fill other columns

Tags: mysql

I have one column in a file line by line, and I want to insert into into the MySQL table.

I also want to ignore rows where the value already exist, and the table has more columns - I want to insert some values into them either.

How can I do that?

I have the following SQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/sample.txt'
IGNORE INTO TABLE 'table'
CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

It will ignore existing lines, but I also want to add NOW() as second's column value, and NULL as third's.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do those columns already exist? It's easiest to just add them with default values (or default NULL). Please post the output from `show create table your_table`

Comment: The simplest way to do this type of operation is to load the file into a temporary staging table, and then use the table to modify the existing table.

Comment: They do exist, but I have to insert predefined values in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table_tmp` (`myfield`);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/sample.txt' INTO TABLE `table_tmp` CHARACTER SET utf8;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` SELECT `myfield`, NOW(), NULL FROM `table_tmp`;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `table_tmp`;
```

Temporary tables are in memory, so this is pretty fast.